# Django registration view not validating form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Would anyone know why the following form is not validating:

forms.py:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password2')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})
        self.fields['username'].required = True
        self.fields['username'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your username'}

        self.fields['email'].widget = EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'})
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your email'}

        self.fields['first_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Forename'})
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your first name'}

        self.fields['last_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Surname'})
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your last name'}

        self.fields['password'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['password'].required = True
        self.fields['password'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your Password'}

        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm password'})
        self.fields['password2'].required = True
        self.fields['password2'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please confirm your Password'}

    def cleaned_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        username_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if username_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("I'm sorry, that username already exists.")

    def cleaned_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("I'm sorry, this email has already been taken.")

    def cleaned_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match.")
```

templates.html:

```
<form class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="." enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.first_name.name }}" {% if form.first_name.value %}value="{{ form.first_name.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Forename"/>
  {% if form.firstname.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.first_name.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.last_name.name }}" {% if form.last_name.value %}value="{{ form.last_name.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Surname"/>
  {% if form.lastname.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.last_name.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.username.name }}"    {% if form.username.value %}value="{{ form.username.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Username"/>
  {% if form.username.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.username.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.email.name }}" {% if form.email.value %}value="{{ form.email.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Email"/>
  {% if form.email.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="{{ form.password.name }}" {% if form.password.value %}value="{{ form.password.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Password"/>
  {% if form.password.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.password.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="{{ form.password2.name }}" {% if form.password2.value %}value="{{ form.password2.value }}"{% endif %} placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
  {% if form.password2.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.password2.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='{{ title }}'>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

The form is just not validating - I guess it could have something to do with the templates.html but it's hard to know exactly as no errors are being thrown back. I'm certainly sure the details I am entering are all correct according to the control flows I have defined.

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    title = "Register"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("The form is valid!")
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user_passsword = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user.set_password(user_password)
            user.save()

            return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', { 'user': user, 'title': title })
    else:
        print("The form is not valid!")
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'oauth/user/registration_form.html', { 'form': form, 'title': title })
```

Please help! I just don't know where I have gone wrong - everything I try just seems to give me "The form is not valid!" in the terminal - I just can't validate this darn form. What am I missing? (It has to be something obvious) :(

Comment: 1) You can see the validation errors in `form.errors`, 2) don't return a blank form (`form = UserRegistrationForm()`) when you re-render the page as none of the errors will be passed through (it's a new form with no data in it). Put the form that is invalid into the context (`form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)`).

Comment: It seems like post data is missing relevant data to fill up a mandatory field. As @JensAstrup mentioned, try debugging with `form.errors`. It will give you `mandatory` and `missing` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this once

```
def register(request):
    title = "Register"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("The form is valid!")
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user_passsword = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user.set_password(user_password)
            user.save()

            return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', { 'user': user, 'title': title })
        else:
            print("The form is not valid!")
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'oauth/user/registration_form.html', { 'form': form, 'title': title })
```

in the template

```
<form class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="." enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.first_name.name }}" {% if form.first_name.value %} value="{{ form.first_name.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Forename"/>
  {% if form.firstname.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.first_name.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.last_name.name }}" {% if form.last_name.value %} value="{{ form.last_name.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Surname"/>
  {% if form.lastname.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.last_name.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.username.name }}"    {% if form.username.value %} value="{{ form.username.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Username"/>
  {% if form.username.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.username.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="{{ form.email.name }}" {% if form.email.value %} value="{{ form.email.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Email"/>
  {% if form.email.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.email.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="{{ form.password.name }}" {% if form.password.value %} value="{{ form.password.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Password"/>
  {% if form.password.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.password.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="{{ form.password2.name }}" {% if form.password2.value %} value="{{ form.password2.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
  {% if form.password2.errors %}<span class="form-error error-above">{{ form.password2.errors.as_text }}</span>{% endif %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='{{ title }}'>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's still not working. Please look at the templates.html I have provided as well - does this look correct?

Comment: still you are getting the form is not valid??

Comment: Yeh - still prints that out. Really can't figure this out! I've followed all the tutorials as correctly as possible but nothing seems to work - all I'm doing is customising the html of the form itself. (I'm using Python 3.6? Django 1.11.1...)

Comment: Debug is set to true, but nothing errors. So it must be in the template.html

Comment: Like I say I've tried it - tried it again and the form is still not valid. I have two password fields (and one password 2 field, so three in total) being rendered in ``{{ form.as_p }}`` ???